# sql function statement w joins & calling specified records via variable assignment in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

first time user of stack here.  Apologies for the long winded title, but i wasn't exactly sure on how to word it. So here's my setup.

Within my functions.php file i have the following sql:

```
function getCustomersTable() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers
                LEFT JOIN leads on customers.customer_id = leads.customer_id
                LEFT JOIN events on customers.customer_id = events.customer_id";
    return resourceToTwoDimensionalArray(query($sql));
}
```

I will be inserting certain data from my query into a html table.  My code for that is:

```
$customers = $getCustomersTable();

foreach($customers as $customer) {
        $id = $customer['customer_id'];
        $title = $customer['event_title'];
        $pickup = $customer['pickup_time'];
        $pickupLocation = $customer['pickup_instructions'];
        $totalPassengers = $customer['num_passengers'];

        // Print the data to the table
        echo "
        <td>$title</td>
        <td>$pickup</td>
        <td>$pickupLocation</td>
        <td>$totalPassengers</td>
        ";
```

When i run it. I get a fatal error "function name must be a string" on $customers = $getCustomersTable();

Any ideas?

Greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$customers = $getCustomersTable();
             ^----
```

You're trying to use a variable function, with an undefined variable. Since the variable's undefined, it's basically acting as the equivalent of

```
$customers = null();
```